# Split tables (one row each) in downward direction

Tags: vba, while-loop, ms-word

I want to split a table in a Word document into multiple tables with only one row each.

I obtained code for splitting a table that moves in an upward direction. It breaks the last row first then moves upward until it reaches the first row of the table.

I created code which attempts to split the table in a downward direction but it only breaks the first row and stops.

Here's the code I created:

```
Dim i As Integer

i = ActiveDocument.Tables.count
Set lasttbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(i)

    Do While lasttbl.Rows.count > 1

        lasttbl.Cell(2, 1).Range.Select
        Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdColumnBreak ' or Selection.SplitTable

    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself. Use the `lasttbl` again inside the loop to recount the tables.

```
Dim i As Integer

i = ActiveDocument.Tables.count
Set lasttbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(i)

    Do While lasttbl.Rows.count > 1

        lasttbl.Cell(2, 1).Range.Select
        Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdColumnBreak ' or Selection.SplitTable

        Set lasttbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(ActiveDocument.Tables.count)
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: But I think there is more simplest way to do this. I don't use the `set lasttbl...` but it returns an _error type mismatch_.